# How to inject an error message into entity without using validation in cakephp3?

Tags: cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-3.x

I have a model which checks a lot of things in beforeSave callback. I do not want to use cakephp validation system for that purpose because it is more simple for me in this case.

If the checking chain fails in somewhere I return false and no saving happens, It is the normal work. I want to give back informal error messages in the entity to use it in the controller and/or view.

How I can do that?

Example:

```
public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options)
{
    if($entity->isNew())
    {
        if(fail1) $entity->inserterrormessage('XYZ is missing');
        if(fail2) $entity->inserterrormessage('Please check if...');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> How I can do that?

Via the `errors()` method, or as of CakePHP 3.4 the `setError()` and `setErrors()` methods.

```
$entity->errors('propertyName', ['Message']);
$entity->setErrors(['propertyName' => ['Message']]);
$entity->setError('propertyName', ['Message']);
```

In case the error isn't related to an actual entity property, just choose a special name, like `_generic`. Alternatively create custom generic error storage functionality in a base entity or trait.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Validation Errors](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#validation-errors)**
- **[API > \Cake\DataSource\EntityTrait::errors()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Datasource.EntityTrait.html#_errors)**
- **[API > \Cake\DataSource\EntityTrait::setError()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Datasource.EntityTrait.html#_setError)**
- **[API > \Cake\DataSource\EntityTrait::setErrors()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Datasource.EntityTrait.html#_setErrors)**